# Is there a way for storing the formatted text in mongodb (e.g bold, red text)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, formatting

Can we store the text as bold or red color in the mongodb.
For Example, I have this bold Text

> **Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.**

I have to keep this text as it is formatted in the mongodb. How can I do that?

Comment: Formatting is something that software does given text content and formatting instructions. You can store an image, or you can convert the text to an SVG, if you want to store the formatted form of the content. (SVG is content and instructions to a software formatter, it should be noted.) Or, you could store your content as something like HTML with CSS directives. The basic point is that text, written words in a language represented as data, is not inherently formatted. Formatting is something you do *with* text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it with the tags that format it.

Take as an example the text you have just written here in stackoverflow. They use a text box for you to write and format your text. What stores the format of that text are basically tags (Eg. `<b>Bold Text!</b>`) that determine how the text should be formatted upon output.

If you are using such a text box, then it should be fairly simple. Hope this helps.